# In which situations can a participant of an Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP) receive an "ESPP refund"?

Tags: united-states, stocks, employment, refund, espp

I believe one reason to receive an ESPP refund is if [the ESPP doesn't allow participants to purchase fractional shares](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/140347/5656) and assuming that the ESPP contribution was not a multiple of the stock price. Is there other situations where a participant of an Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP) can receive an "ESPP refund"?

E.g., screenshot from UltiPro:

[image]

Comment: Do people still have ESPPs? Became a rather useless instrument, at least in the US

Comment: @littleadvl yes. Why useless?

Comment: Because of IRC Sec. 423? For many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan. To your question: read the plan documents.

Comment: @littleadv [What's new in the IRC Sec. 423 that caused that for many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/152083/5656)