# What's new in the IRC Sec. 423 that caused that for many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan?

Tags: united-states, employment, espp

I read these [comments](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/152079/5656):

> - [littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv) [3 hours ago](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152079/in-which-situations-can-a-participant-of-an-employee-stock-purchase-plan-espp#comment308895_152079): Do people still have ESPPs? Became a rather useless instrument, at least in the US .
> - [OP](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/5656/franck-dernoncourt) [3 hours ago](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152079/in-which-situations-can-a-participant-of-an-employee-stock-purchase-plan-espp#comment308896_152079) Yes. Why useless?
> - [littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv) [2 hours ago](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152079/in-which-situations-can-a-participant-of-an-employee-stock-purchase-plan-espp#comment308897_152079):  Because of IRC Sec. 423? For many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan.

What's new in the IRC Sec. 423 that caused that for many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan?

Comment: Nothing new but inflation, not sure what your question is about.

Comment: @littleadv why is inflation causing that for many employers the benefit to employees is not worth the cost of managing the plan nowadays?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'll simply copy the answer that was posted as a comment here:

> Nothing new but inflation, not sure what your question is about. 
> – [littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv)
>  [Aug 8 at 0:58](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152083/whats-new-in-the-irc-sec-423-that-caused-that-for-many-employers-the-benefit-t#comment308905_152083)